# Копировать текст в буфер обмена js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть блок в который через бекенд передается значение

```
<div   id="tech-inf" class="tech_info" data-help="Select to copy">
              {{ pw.account_info_config|tojson }}
```

как сделать на js или jquery что бы я смог по нажатию на блок скопировать тект который приходит мне?

```
$("#tech-inf").click(function () {
  CopyToClipboard('info_tech');
});
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {

  // Create a "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");

  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);

  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);

  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();

  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
```

так не работает(

Comment: Что-то похожее, может быть поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: Для начала имя функции в объявлении и в вызове клика разные. `CopyToClipboard`  !== `copyToClipboard`

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос много просматривают, поэтому соберу сюда более общие примеры.

---

Для копирования существует метод `document.execCommand('copy')`, он копирует текущий выделенный текст на странице, если был вызван пользователем (например, при клике). Т.е. не получится просто запустить скрипт на странице и подсунуть любому посетителю текст без его ведома.

Выделение текста непосредственно из блока достаточно муторно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard

А для элементов `<textarea>` и `<input>` есть простой метод `.select()`

Поэтому проще создать дополнительное поле, отправить туда необходимый текст и скопировать его оттуда. И хорошо бы оформить это в виде функции, которая получает строку - копирует строку:

```
function copyToClipboard(str) {
  var area = document.createElement('textarea');

  document.body.appendChild(area);  
    area.value = str;
    area.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(area);  
}
```

Далее, захочется как-то оповестить человеку, что копирование сработало. Это тоже может быть в виде функции, которая получает кнопку, меняет её детали, а через пару секунд возвращает всё на место. Примерно так:

```
function ui_copyDone(btn) {
  var contentSaved = btn.innerHTML;

  btn.innerHTML = 'Скопирова<span style="color: red;">но</span>';
  btn.classList.add('copied'); // уже в CSS к классу .copied дописать любые детали

  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.innerHTML = contentSaved;
    btn.classList.remove('copied');
  }, 1500);
}
```

В итоге задача сводится только к тому, как вы будете передавать текст в функцию. А это уже достаточно просто. Несколько примеров:

На jQuery:

```js
$('.js-copy').on('click', function() {
  copyToClipboard( $(this).text() );
  ui_copyDone( this ); 
  // this → объект, в контексте которого вызвана функция (здесь: кликнутый HTML элемент
  // $(this) → оно же, завернутое в jQuery-объект.
});

$('.js-copy-btn').each(function(index) {
  $(this).on('click', function() {    
    copyToClipboard( $('.js-copy-target').eq(index).text() );
    ui_copyDone( this );
  });  
  // this → очередной элемент, который перебираем
  // index → его номер, который совпадает с номером блока, откуда нужно копировать
});

/***/

function copyToClipboard(str) {
  var area = document.createElement('textarea');

  document.body.appendChild(area);
    area.value = str;
    area.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(area);
}

function ui_copyDone(btn) {
  var contentSaved = btn.innerHTML;
  
  btn.innerHTML = 'Скопирова<span style="color: red;">но</span>';
  btn.classList.add('copied');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.innerHTML = contentSaved;
    btn.classList.remove('copied');
  }, 1500);
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copied {
  border-color: #045acf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-copy box">1. Кликни и копируй меня!</div>
<div class="js-copy box">2. Кликни и копируй меня!</div>

<hr>

<div class="js-copy-target box">1 1 1 1</div>
<button class="js-copy-btn">Скопировать</button>

<div class="js-copy-target box">2 2 2 2</div>
<button class="js-copy-btn">Скопировать</button>
```

И то же самое без jQuery:

```js
setAutoCopyFeatures()

/***/

function setAutoCopyFeatures() {
  onclick_copySelf(); /* class="js-copy" */
  onclick_copyFrom(); /* class="js-copy-btn", "js-copy-target" */
  
  // Открыл функцию - сразу видно, что она делает
  // Не вдаваясь в подробности, можно вспомнить, какие классы нужно добавить в HTML  
  
  function onclick_copySelf() {
    let copy = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copy');
    
    for( let i = 0; i < copy.length; i++ ) {
      copy[i].addEventListener('click', function() {        
        copyToClipboard( this.textContent );
        ui_copyDone( this );
      });
    }
  }
  
  function onclick_copyFrom() {
    let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copy-btn');
    
    for( let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++ ) {
      btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let div = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copy-target');
        
        copyToClipboard( div[i].textContent );
        ui_copyDone( this );
      });
    }
  }
  
  /***/

  function copyToClipboard(str) {
    var area = document.createElement('textarea');

    document.body.appendChild(area);
    area.value = str;
    area.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(area);
  }

  function ui_copyDone(btn) {
    var contentSaved = btn.innerHTML;

    btn.innerHTML = 'Скопирова<span style="color: red;">но</span>';
    btn.classList.add('copied');

    setTimeout(function() {
      btn.innerHTML = contentSaved;
      btn.classList.remove('copied');
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copied {
  border-color: #045acf;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-copy box">1. Кликни и копируй меня!</div>
<div class="js-copy box">2. Кликни и копируй меня!</div>

<hr>

<div class="js-copy-target box">1 1 1 1</div>
<button class="js-copy-btn">Скопировать</button>

<div class="js-copy-target box">2 2 2 2</div>
<button class="js-copy-btn">Скопировать</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {

  // Create a "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");

  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);

  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);

  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();

  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  
  console.log(document.

}

$("#tech-inf").click(function () {
  copyToClipboard('tech-inf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div   id="tech-inf" class="tech_info" data-help="Select to copy">
{{ pw.account_info_config|tojson }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не помню где брал код, но работает отлично.

```js
$('#copy').on('click',function(){
  var code = document.querySelector('#text'); // #text - блок из которого нужно скопировать
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(code);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful?'удачно':'неудачно';
    alert('Код скопирован '+msg);
  } catch(err) {
    alert('Код не скопирован автоматически :с'+'\n'+'Попробуйте вручную');
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">Какой-то текст который нужно скопировать</div>
<button id="copy">Скопировать текст из блока</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, так проще всего:
[Код](https://codepen.io/KorniloFF/pen/KKMQaqV?editors=1010)

```
node.addEventListener('click', $e=>{
var t= $e.currentTarget;
var r = document.createRange();

r.selectNode(t);
document.getSelection().addRange(r);
document.execCommand('copy');
alert('Текст скопирован в буфер обмена');
})
```