# Как скопировать текст в теге <p> при нажатии на него?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p class="dialog-header">Ваш промокод:</p>    
<p class="promokode" id="promokodeID">12345abc</p> <!--При нажатии на него нужно его же скопировать-->
<p class="promokode-description">Нажмите на него, чтобы скопировать</p>
```

Comment: Однако, во - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822556/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-js-or-jquery/969719#969719

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
document.querySelector('#promokodeID').addEventListener(
  'click',
  async (event) => {
    const code = event.target.innerText;
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(code);
    alert(`${code} copied!`);
  }
);
```

Comment: А для чего тут async, если работает и без этого?

Comment: Если нужно дождаться завершения копирования и выдать какой-то знак, нужна асинхронная функция, чтобы использовать `await`, так как `.writeText()` возвращает Promise.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt спасибо) Это именно то, что нужно)