# Как при клике на кнопку скопировать её содержимое?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при клике на кнопку скопировать её содержимое в буфер обмена?

```css
.gift-certificate-download__action-btn-copy {
        margin-right: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 6px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 140%;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
        color: #181818;
        background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<button class="gift-certificate-download__action-btn-copy">8МАРТА</button>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822556#answer-969719

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять его значение `text`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.gift-certificate-download__action-btn-copy', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.gift-certificate-download__action-btn-copy {
        margin-right: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 6px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 140%;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
        color: #181818;
        background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="gift-certificate-download__action-btn-copy">8МАРТА</button>
```

Comment: Работает то хорошо, но нужно просто скопировать.

Comment: @Krovorgen вы умеете заводить переменные и класть туда значения?)

Comment: думаю пока на вёрстку способен я

Comment: вот нужно узнать как объявить переменную и положить туда значение и всё)

Comment: Вопрос скорее: как скопировать содержимое кнопки в `буфер обмена`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson не факт. Пусть автор уточнит в таком случае

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В описании вопроса и указано, при клике на кнопку, скопировать её содержимое, а именно текст внутри кнопки

Comment: @Krovorgen можно скопировать куда угодно, можно  в буфер, а можно в переменную, а можно в outputStream

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Тогда нужно именно в буфер, вопрос поправил

Comment: @Krovorgen тогда скорее всего подойдут ответы по ссылке, которую оставил OPTIMUSPRIME  из вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/822556/191482